# Downloading from web using threads(inside a separate process) and multiprocessing queues

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I have the following class to download from web:

```
class Downloader:
   
  SENTINEL = END_QUEUE_SENTINEL

    def __init__(self, to_download, downloaded):
        self.to_download = to_download
        self.downloaded = downloaded
        self.mutex = Lock()
        self._stop_workers = False

    @staticmethod
    def _write_to_file(path, content):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
        with open(path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(content)

    def _set_item(self, response: HTTPResponse, item):
        if response.status == 200:
            self._write_to_file(item.download_path, content=response.read())
            return item

    def _download_item(self):
        while not self._stop_workers:
            item: = self.to_download.get()
            if item == self.SENTINEL:
                print("sentinel received")
                self.mutex.acquire()
                self._stop_workers = True
                print("self._stop_workers becomes True")
                self.mutex.release()
                print("mutex_released")
                print(self.to_download.qsize())
                break
              req = urlrequest.Request(item.url)
              response = urlrequest.urlopen(req)
              item = self._set_item(response, item)
              self.downloaded.put(item)

    def download_items(self, download_workers=50):
        threads = [Thread(target=self._download_item) for _ in range(download_workers)]
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
        print("workers stopped")
        self._stop_workers = False
        self.downloaded.put(self.SENTINEL)
```

`to_download` and `downloaded` are multiprocessing Queues.

A different process is adding data to `to_download` queue.

```
downloader = Downloader(to_download,downloaded)
processes = [Process(target=add_item_to_download),
             Process(target=downloader.download_items,
                     kwargs={"download_workers": 10})]

        for p in processes:
            p.start()

        for p in processes:
            p.join()
```

`item` is an object that has 2 attributes, url and download_path.

The first process after a time is sending a sentinel into `Downloader`
The sentinel is received, the following is printed:
"sentinel received"
"self._stop_workers becomes True"
"mutex_released"
"0" # qsize

and then nothing happens, the process/threads hangs, and even with Pycharm debugging I can't find why this is happening.

The expectation was to finish the thread "join" and print:
""workers stopped" and add the sentinel to the downloaded queue.

Comment: `concurrent.futures` is a standard python library that has friendly wrappers for stuff like this, it supports both `Thread` and `Process` pools via `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor`, It also handles the mutex for us using `Semaphore`

Comment: I fixed my example it's now fully working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things. Since there is no type hinting, I'll just assume `self.to_download` is an iterable and can therefore be iterated through using a `for` loop.

Also, this looks like it is sending http requests with urllib. There a few improvements here too.

urllib supports streaming downloads directly to file with `urlretrieve` which could save memory depending on download size.

`Process` pools are for CPU-bound tasks that need to run in true parallel, looping network calls is more of an I/O-bound task, So I would recommend using `Thread` pools instead for this problem. I used `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which wraps `Thread`, if you really need true parallel threads and not just concurrency, use `ProcessPoolExecutor`, which wraps `Process`, but know that memory sharing is not as complete using a process pool.

Example below:

```py
import urllib.request as urlrequest
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor,Future,wait
import typing as T

# quick hacky Item class with constructor
Item = lambda url,download_path: \
    type('Item',(),{'url':url,'download_path':download_path})

# Our ThreadPoolExecutor now manages thread state for us
# No need for class any more to track state, pure function will do
def download_items(items: T.Generator[Item,None,None], download_workers: int = 50):
    # Allocate Thread pool with download_workers Thread
    thread_pool: ThreadPoolExecutor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=download_workers)
    # Any mutable Iteratble structure will work here (I chose list)
    threads: T.List[Future] = []
    for item in items:
        # Submit our urlretrieve calls to thread pool
        threads.append(thread_pool.submit(urlrequest.urlretrieve,item.url,item.download_path))
    # Blocks main until all threads complete
    wait(threads)
    print("All threads complete")

if __name__=='__main__':
    urls: T.Tuple[str] = ("https://stackoverflow.com","https://google.com","https://reddit.com")
    paths: T.Tuple[str] = ("./stackoverflow.html","./google.html","./reddit.html")
    items: T.Generator[Item,None,None] = (Item(url,path) for url,path in zip(urls,paths))
    download_items(items)
```